# Dejar solo los ultimos 4 caracteres Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Tengo el texto *SAR_aPP.D7HG32689* , y solo quiero obtener los ultimos 4 caracteres, en este caso sería *2689*, pero puede ser otro, ya que le texto se arma aleatorio y la cantidad total de caracteres tambien puede variar.

¿Cómo puedo obtener esto con `sed`?

Yo intenté con:

```
$ sed 's/SAR_aPP.//g'
```

Para quitar la primera parte, pero lo que sigue no tengo idea.

Intente con: `cut -c`, pero solo pude ver que quita caracteres de adelante para atras, o no se usarlo correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular: `(.{4})$`, que encierra en un grupo aquellas cadenas que tengan cuatro caracteres y que estén antes de llegar al final de línea.

### Usando `sed`

Su uso con `sed` es:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(.{4})$/\1/g
```

Donde `-r` habilita el uso de expresiones regulares extendidas, y el metacaracter `\1` indica que lo matcheado (la cadena de cuatro dígitos), se va a mostrar; lo demás no.

Ejemplo generando 2 numeros aleatorios de 5 cifras:

```
$ shuf -i 10000-90000 -n 2 | xargs -I {} echo 'SAR_aPP.D7HG{}' | sed -r 's/.*(.{4})$/\1/g'
8607
7169
```

### Usando `grep`

Pero también puedes con `grep -Po '.{4}$'`:

```
$ shuf -i 10000-90000 -n 2 | xargs -I {} echo 'SAR_aPP.D7HG{}' | grep -Po '.*\K(.{4})$'
2071
2481
```

### Usando `cut`

Puedes usar un workaround con `cut`:

```
$ shuf -i 10000-90000 -n 2 | xargs -I {} echo 'SAR_aPP.D7HG{}' | rev | cut -c 1-4 | rev
1817
9935
```

Aquí utilicé `rev` en cada renglón para que invirtiera el orden. Así, `cut` ya puede tomar los primeros cuatro (que eran los últimos), y luego esos cuatro los vuelve a invertir con otro `rev`.

### Con la shell

También puedes utilizar las herramientas de la shell:

En Bash o en Zsh:

```
$ cadena=SAR_aPP.D7HG32689
$ echo ${cadena: -4}
2689
```

Comment: gracias funciono